# How do I automate instantiation of OWL ontological classes?

Tags: python, semantic-web, ontology, owl

Given a certain OWL, I would like automate the classification of data based on the classes and properties defined in the ontology.

I developed my ontology in Protegè, in OWL format. It would be nice to have, for example, some sort of code generator which could parse the OWL and give me back a Python module where the Ontological classes were mapped to Python classes. From Such a module, I could write a script to scan my data and populate the ontology with instances of the classes representing my data.

Does anyone know of such a tool?

Comment: Don't know why someone marked you down on this question. Seems perfectly reasonable, with maybe a few grammatical errors. +1

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at RDF Alchemy:

http://www.openvest.com/trac/wiki/RDFAlchemy

It is a ORDFM for Python. It doesn't generate a load of python classes from OWL, rather supports mapping python classes to terms in an ontology thus providing a way do serialise instances of objects to RDF.

For a pure OWL to Class generator, you might need to look at Java API's in particular, Jastor:

http://jastor.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for the link the RDFAlchemy, but what I really need is a tool to help me instantiate an ontology, preferable in Python. Maybe that is not a common task, but is exactly why I developed my ontology in the first place: To be able to classify stuff with it.